# Background color not change TextEditor view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, background-color

```
//.........some other views........

       ZStack(alignment: .leading ) {
            
            Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()
            TextEditor(text: $mytext)
                .background(Color.orange)
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                .frame(width: 362, height: 400)
            

        }
```

Background color remains Color.white for all cases i applied so what's wrong here? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to clear default background color via appearance

```
    init() {
        UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
```

and then `background` modifier works in any mode

```
    TextEditor(text: $mytext)
        .background(Color.orange)
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

Comment: Learnt another thing from you again. Thanks.

Comment: Sir this way work thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't really change the `background` of **SwiftUI TextEditor**. Either material/shape/color is not possible for applying as a background of SwiftUI TextEditor.

However, you can multiply the color of your TextEditor which provides a similar result to the general background(.color) except it's not really a background color.

```
 TextEditor(text: $mytext)
            .colorMultiply(.orange) //modified
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            .frame(width: 362, height: 400)
```

Comment: This will not work in dark-mode, anything multiplied on 0 (black) is zero. Just be aware.